# Java цикл foreach

Tags: java

Есть функция foo, которая возвращает массив bar.
Будет ли одинакова последовательность работы у цикла foreach, если в качестве иттерируемого объекта передать foo и bar? Будет ли вызваться функция foo каждый раз или условно закешируется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работать будет одинаково. При вызове `for (Object a : foo()) {}` у вас сначала один раз вызовется метод, по результату которого пойдёт итерирование.
`foreach` - всего лишь "синтаксический сахар" для создания итератора и дальнейшего его использования. Т.е. "под капотом" это:

```
Iterator it = foo().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    it.next();
}
```

Comment: Почитайте тему чем отличается `Iterator` от цикла и как не следует писать циклы и итераторы.
Эта функция не может закешироваться, по одной простой причине  - как к массиву обратиться без функции и ее выполнения - вы не записываете ее никуда, а исполняете повторно, так как данные внутри нее не всегда статические - но обращение к функции происходит постоянно в любых случаях, даже если и статическая функция ее нужно вызвать (выполнить), в случае переменной, работает иначе, так как это уже ранее записанные данные отработанной функции.